# Syncfusion PDF Images Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

Currently Im producing a dynamic PDF from my Xamarin.ios application. However, what im currently trying to do is add a custom list class which contains a byte array (Image) and a string for the image caption. However, when I produce the PDF document, I use a foreach loop over the results contained in the list to get each image byte array and corresponding caption.

The problem im having is that when I get the generated PDF, it seems to print 4 of the images out to the PDF. Im not sure if im doing something wrong but cannot see if I am?

Creation of Image part of PDF Grid:

```
        #region ATTACHED IMAGES GRID
        PdfGrid imagesGrid = new PdfGrid();

        imagesGrid.Columns.Add(2);
        imagesGrid.Columns[0].Width = 110;
        imagesGrid.Columns[1].Width = 400;

        PdfGridRow imagesGridTitle = imagesGrid.Rows.Add();
        imagesGridTitle.Cells[0].Value = "Attached Photos";


        AddImages(imagesGrid);


        #region CUSTOMISE STYLES

        imagesGrid.Style.CellPadding = generalPadding;

        imagesGridTitle.ApplyStyle(pdfGridHeaderStyle);



        imagesGrid.Rows.SetSpan(0, 0, 1, 2);

        #endregion
```

Method for creating the extra rows dynamically:

```
private static void AddImages(PdfGrid imagesGrid)
    {
        foreach (var image in FormResults.photoResults)
        {
            PdfGridRow newGridRow = imagesGrid.Rows.Add();
            newGridRow.Cells[0].Value = image.Caption;
            newGridRow.Cells[1].Value = CreatePDFImage(image.ImageByte);

            newGridRow.Cells[1].ImagePosition = PdfGridImagePosition.Fit;
        }
    }
```

Method for creating the pdfimage from a byte array:

```
private static PdfImage CreatePDFImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        MemoryStream imageMs = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        PdfImage image = new PdfBitmap(imageMs);

        return image;
    }
```

lastly, my custom list class:

```
public class PhotoResults
    {
        public byte[] ImageByte { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be achievable using BeginCellLayout event handler. Please find the sample and output PDF below for your reference.

**Sample:** http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/217022/ze/Sample1494155968

**Output PDF:**  http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/217022/ze/output-1577237401

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply and sorry for taking so long to respond. However, How would this be able to be implemented when I need to loop over my custom list and set a new row for each piece of data in the list? The example shows me how to implement the event handler but not actually how I would do it for my situation?

Comment: @JamieLeech, you can use the above BeginCellLayout event handler to draw the image in cell bounds. Could you please confirm whether your requirement is to preserve the image in cell bounds? If yes,then the image can be preserved in cell bounds by changing the ImagePosition from Fit to Stretch.Can you please try in your end. If you still have a query, kindly create a support ticket with the detailed information of your requirement.It will be helpful for us to check and provide you the solution.The support ticket can be created using below link.
 [1]: https://www.syncfusion.com/account/login